# Specific values from PHP Session Array show up when 'echo'-ed on PC but don't show up on android (just blank space). How to Fix?

Tags: php, android, session-variables, compatibility, cross-device

I have made a program that is made to test me on Korean Vocabulary so that I can learn Korean. The thing is, when I try to use the website I made on my android phone, none of the variables which have been extracted from a session array show up, instead there is just a blank space. PIC Below. How do I rectify this?

**4 pics, 1 of each file concerned, 1 of the PC view of the website and one of the Android view.**

[image]

I tried using print_r instead before asking this question but that didn't work.

Comment: **I dont see a** `session_start()` anywhere. Is it that obvious

Comment: By the way, Pictures are not recomended, paste real code not pictures of code

Comment: The session_start() is at the very top. If there was no session start even the computer version wouldn't work.

Comment: How much of it should I paste?